# Scaffold-DbContext - how to prevent it from adding few same columns such as ID, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, etc

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

All tables have few same columns (ID, CreatedDate, CreatedBy). I want to use these columns in new BaseEntity.cs, then bind it to all entities. I don't have to remove these columns and bind BaseEntity.cs in one by one entity class after entering scaffold-dbcontext command. Is it possible to do that?

I do not want to get auto entity generated after using scaffold-dbcontext like this.

```
public partial class User 
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
       public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get like this. Scaffold-DbContext without adding ID, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.

```
public partial class User 
{
       public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can use ID, CreatedDate and CreatedBy in BaseEntity.cs and bind it to all entities classes. I don't have to remove 3 columns manually from every entity classes after every scaffold-dbcontext command.

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
       public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public partial class User : BaseEntity
{
       public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base Dto class with CreatedBy, CreatedDate ... properties, and then override `SaveChanges()` method in your `DbContext`  to make those changes on update and on create for every entity. Like this:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
            {
                if (_contextAuditor != null)
                {
                    Update(ChangeTracker.Entries());
                    Create(ChangeTracker.Entries());
                }

                return base.SaveChanges();
            }

public void Update(IEnumerable<EntityEntry> changedEntities)
        {
            IEnumerable<EntityEntry> editedEntities = changedEntities
                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .ToList();

            foreach (EntityEntry entity in editedEntities)
            {
                if (entity.Entity is IUpdateableDtoModel updateableEntity)
                {
                    updateableEntity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    updateableEntity.UpdatedBy = GetCurrentUserName();
                }
            }
        }

 public void Create(IEnumerable<EntityEntry> changedEntities)
        {
            IEnumerable<EntityEntry> createdEntities = changedEntities
                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
                .ToList();

            foreach (EntityEntry entity in createdEntities)
            {
                if (entity.Entity is ICreateableDtoModel updateableEntity)
                {
                    updateableEntity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    updateableEntity.CreatedBy = updateableEntity.CreatedBy ?? GetCurrentUserName();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, I am not talking about saving/updating records. I mean auto entity and DbContext generated using Scaffold-DbContext command in nuget manager console.